# Make PC act as WiFi Access Point, DHCP Server and File Server - How?

Tags: networking, wireless, android, dhcp, ios

Is it possible to setup a PC running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to

1. Act as a WiFi access point
2. DHCP server
3. File server

I would like to install an Ubuntu PC in an automobile. It would *not* have internet access. However, I would like for Android and iOS phones and tablets to be able to connect to it via wifi and then stream video files stored on the Ubuntu PC (in a USB drive connected to the Ubuntu PC). Is this possible?

I've read that as of Ubuntu 16, the PC can create an ad-hoc WiFi network that devices (e.g. Android and iOS) can use, but all of those articles I've read also refer to the Ubuntu PC being connected to the internet by a wired ethernet connection. I'm unclear whether the PC *must* have an internet connection for this to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible* Having internet connection has nothing to do with this set up**

*WiFi access point will depends on your wifi card and drivers, not ALL drivers support turning it into WiFI access point

**On second though the iOS or android might not like connecting to networks without internet? Not sure, unplug your internet cable from your WiFi router and try to connect to it from your device? But this really has nothing to do with ubuntu

***on third thought, it probably won't work. Mobile devices want to see internet, they'll probably think you need to authenticate and try to open a web browser. Not sure if you can tell them to connect without internet. Ask on iOS and android forums